# Android: Set a readable font size for webView

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm using webView to display HTML content.
The text size is readable for tablets. However on small smartphones, the text appears as dots. The user has to pinch-zoom to read it.
Is there any way to set a fixed size which will be readable on both tablets and smartphones?

Comment: Did you happen to solve this problem?

Comment: This code finally solved my problem:
  articleWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);

Answer (score 1):

```
WebSettings ws= webView.getSettings();
```

- setTextSize:

  `ws.setTextSize(ws.TextSize.NORMAL);`

Enum for specifying the text size.
`SMALLEST` is 50%, 
`SMALLER` is 75%, 
`NORMAL` is 100%, 
`LARGER` is 150%, 
`LARGEST` is 200%,

- Or use this one

  `ws.setDefaultFontSize(12);`

Comment: it says websetting.TextSize is deprecated.

Comment: If you are using API 14 or greater, then you should look at "public synchronized void setTextZoom(int textZoom)", in this default 100, you can change that using this method.

Comment: @PriteshDesai: Also check "websetting.setDefaultFixedFontSize(size)", default value is 16 here, you can increase if you want. Hope this helps.