# change textsize in android webview

Tags: android, android-webview, android-fonts

In my application I am using webview. I want to change font size in webview,so I am doing it as:

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(25);
```

But it does not reflect text size change. I also tried  using

```
loadUrl("javascript:(document.body.style.fontSize ='25pt');");
```

But still no luck. If I change .css file as

```
body {
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 25px;
color: #495A69;
background-color: #fff;
padding: 0 16px 16px;
}
```

Then it works. But I want to change Text size at runtime, Therefore I cant use this working css file. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try out with this method webSettings.setTextZoom(90); ..hope it works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796176/how-to-change-the-fontsize-in-an-android-webview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051886/android-set-a-readable-font-size-for-webview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this to zoom the text size

```
WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
 settings.setTextZoom(settings.getTextZoom() + 10);
```

or use

```
WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.LARGER);
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion,But my current min sdk version is 10,and for your suggestion it requires api level 14

Comment: use the second option in the answer

Comment: settings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.LARGER); works . Thanks

Comment: First option work for me.Second option is deprecated now.